# Online time series algorithms implemented in R/python/MOA

Tags: time-series, online-algorithm

I am looking for implemented online learning time series algorithms. Does R, Python, MOA or any other tools have these kind of algorithms implemented?

TIA!

Comment: What kind of online learning time series algorithms are you looking for? Pattern matching with given template? Motif discovery?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late, but in case someone is looking for the answer, I will share what I know:

**PYTHON: sklearn clustering algorithms.**
[MiniBatchKMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html) and [Birch](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.Birch.html#sklearn-cluster-birch): both algorithm implementations have a partial_fit method allowing you to stream data through them in incremental updates (allowing online learning).

**JAVA: MOA framework.**
There are a lot of well known stream clustering algorithms implemented (CluStream, DenStream, etc ...). You can use it via:

- terminal
- user interface (see [clustering demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXRH-qkB-dE&list=LLabeTVETICtTiqOkPGSSmOA&index=4&t=0s))
- code (Java API)

See the '[downloads](https://moa.cms.waikato.ac.nz/downloads/)' section in the MOA web, or check directly the source code on [Github](https://github.com/waikato/moa).

**R: [streamMOA](https://github.com/mhahsler/streamMOA)**: a R package that acts as a *wrapper* for the MOA [Java] classes. See the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/streamMOA/streamMOA.pdf).